# get average of given dates in php

Tags: php, laravel, date

I try to get an average of given dates but I failed when dates are from two different years. I need something like this

given dates:
`2017-06-1`
`2017-06-3`
`2017-06-4`
`2017-06-3`
`2017-06-5`

output : `2017-06-4`

this is my code:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $total+= date('z', strtotime($date))+1;
}
$avg_day = $total/sizeof($dates);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('z Y', $avg_day . ' ' . date("Y"));
```

but my code is not working for

given dates:
`2016-12-29`
`2016-12-31`
`2017-01-1`
`2017-01-5`
`2017-01-3`

Comment: How you get these dates ? From database ?

Comment: dates come with other data.

Comment: can you find smallest date ?

Comment: doesn't need to find smallest date.

Comment: I have posted answer, take a moment to view it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have problem with averaging year. So, You can do this to get average.

Just an algorithm:

1. Find smallest date among your dates at first as `$smallest`
2. Initiate a variable `$total = 0;`
3. Add difference of each date in days with smallest date.
4. Find average from total.
5. Add this total to smallest date.

Here, You have smallest as `$smallest = '2016-12-29'`

```
$total = 0;
$dates = ['2016-12-29', '2016-12-31', '2017-01-1', '2017-01-5', '2017-01-3'];

$smallest = min($dates);
$smallest = Carbon::parse($smallest);
foreach($dates as $date){
    $d = Carbon::parse($date);
    $total = $total+$smallest->diffInDays($d);
}
$average_day = $total/sizeof($dates);
$average_date = $smallest->addDays($average_day);
```

Hope, This might help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can work with timestamp of the date and use `avg()` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-average) of the `Illuminate\Support\Collection`

```
$dates = [
    '2016-12-29', '2016-12-31', '2017-01-1', '2017-01-5', '2017-01-3'
];

$dateCollection = collect();

foreach($dates as $date){
    $dateCollection->push((new \DateTime($date))->getTimestamp());
}

$averageTimestamp = $dateCollection->avg(); //timestamp value
$averageDate = date('Y-m-d', $average);
```

Or using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) package:

```
$dateCollection->push(Carbon::parse($date)->timestamp);
...
$averageDate = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($average)->toDateString();
```

Comment: it gives me output like `1483263360`

Comment: I changed my answer. See now, please

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working for your base dates. The correct output for

> 2017-06-1 2017-06-3 2017-06-4 2017-06-3 2017-06-5

is

> 2017-06-03

According to OpenOffice calc, and overall logic (a date is represented by epoch number)

Check out this script

```
$dates = ['2017-06-1 ', '2017-06-3', '2017-06-4', '2017-06-3', '2017-06-5'];
$dates = array_map('strtotime', $dates);
$average = date('Y-m-d', array_sum($dates) / count($dates)); // 2017-06-03 (1496490480)

echo $average;
```

Keep simple tasks simple